# computing cdf $\chi^2_3$ in Matlab

Tags: matlab, chi-squared

I have still another problem with `chi2` in Matlab:
How can I compute the vector c.d.f.
This doesn't work

`chi2([0:0.01:1],3)` ?

**EDIT**

I was trying to obtain the 3 numbers from the bottom snippet (for $m=3$) but I've obtained different numbers:

> > mean(chi2pdf([0:0.01:1],3))

ans =

```
0.1979
```

> > max(chi2pdf([0:0.01:1],3))

ans =

```
0.2420
```

> > 

[image]

Comment: What is your MATLAB version? use chi2cdf(x,v) instead. search "chi2cdf" in the help and it gives you details on how this function works. Basically it calculates the values of CDF at given array (or matrix or higher dimensional objects) of $x$ for the degrees of freedom specified at $v$. $x,v$ must have the same dimension, unless you use scalar $v$ which accounts for all $x$.

Comment: @K.K.McDonald the version is `2017a`. Please see my **EDIT**.

Comment: You are using the functions wrong. Mean function returns the mean value of a given array and not the mean of the CDF. If you want the mean of CDF, you have to calculate it using integrating or by creating a probability distribution object, not a number array! Please see this guide [mean of distribution](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.mean.html)

Comment: there is even no chi2 [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.mean.html). Could you eventually write form me the 3 commands for mean mode and median for `chi2` from either pdf or cdf so that I obtain the values from the snippet ??it will be better to compute them from arrays given than objects ...Thank you!

Comment: You can get Chi-square using Gamma, see here [Chi-square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#:~:text=The%20chi%2Dsquared%20distribution%20is,in%20construction%20of%20confidence%20intervals.). And then you can get any desired value of Gamma/ Chi-square as explained here [Gamma](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.gammadistribution.html).